# How to implement routing in angular2 for user profile

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How to implement the user profile routing like this for username mark

```
mydomain.com/mark
```

and how to fetch the value of username 'mark' in the component?

Any sample code to implement this?

[Modified question with example]

Answer (score 0):

**app/app.routes.ts**

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent }  from './home.component';
import { ContactCompnent }    from './contact.component';
import {UserComponent} from './user.component';
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactCompnent },
  { path: '<user>', component: UserComponent }
];
export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Component Router</h1>
    <nav>
      <a [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>
      <a [routerLink]="['/contact']">Contact</a>
       <a [routerLink]="['/<user>']">user</a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

Check live example here,

https://plnkr.co/edit/ySW9sYyV8Ou7tQB7biyx?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you help me in giving router link for example
How to use the routerLink for user Mark

<a [routerLink]="['/mark']">Mark</a>

and how to fetch this value (mark) in the component UserComponent ?

I tried with few changes but they are not working.